# Sql 2008 not allowing me to make changes to a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

For some reason sql server 2008 is not allowing me to add columns to an existing table.

The table is empty btw.

Is there a setting that prevents modifying tables in sql 2008?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can change a setting to stop this. Details [here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/455560.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

When you use SSMS to design a table in a database and then try to make a change to the table structure--such as adding a column that is not at the end--the table has to be recreated. The default setting is that you are not allowed to save any changes that require recreation.

You can:

1. Go to Tools | Options | Designers | Tables and Designers and uncheck the *Prevent Saving Changes that require table re-creation* option.
2. Script out the change and run it yourself.

**WARNING**

Be aware that the reason this is set as a default is that recreating your table can be extremely harmful in a production database, and there are edge cases where the automatic scripting can get something wrong. What if you had a really complicated partitioned table on multiple file groups with billions of rows? Assuming you actually had the enormous space required for two copies of the table plus an absolutely gargantuan transaction log, this would clobber your whole database for hours and possibly mess up the final result anyway. Or, what if your new table could not be inserted to (as in the case of a non-null column being added with no default)--then the script could fail the insert step without recovering properly, and you end up with an empty table.

Idea: back up first!

Don't do anything if you don't understand the risks.

**Example of LOST DATA**

Here is [a perfect example of someone losing data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17244518/57611) through using this option. Don't say I didn't warn you.