# SQL Server wiped my table after (incorrectly) creating a new column .. what the heck happened?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I added a new column to an existing table in the SQL Server Management Studio table designer.  Type INT, not null.  *Didn't set a default value.*

I generated a change script and ran it, it errored out with a warning that the new column does not allow nulls, and no default value was being set.  It said "0 rows affected".

Data was still there, and for some reason my new column was visible in the "columns" folder on the database tree on the left of SSMS even though it said "0 rows affected" and failed to make the database change.

Because the new column was visible in the list, I thought I would go ahead and update all rows and add a value in.

```
UPDATE MyTable SET NewColumn = 0
```

Boom.. table wiped clean.  Every row deleted.

This is a big problem because it was on a production database that wasn't being backed up unbeknownst to me.  But.. recoverable with some manual entry, so not the end of the world.

Anyone know what could have happened here.. and maybe what was going on internally that could have caused my update statement to wipe out every row in the table?

Comment: `UPDATE MyTable SET NewColumn = 0` won't have lost the rows (except if you have a poorly coded `UPDATE` trigger). It must have been another step that lost them.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the change script? Did that change script rename the table, make a new table with the new column, and copy all the data from the old one, then finally drop the old one? I suspect that the new load went wrong, and then the changes were committed... sadly. This makes sense because trying to insert the old values into the new table, when the new column was set to `NOT NULL` and no default was specified, is exactly the kind of error one could expect to occur. Moral of the story: don't commit until you're sure it all looks good.

Comment: @ErikE - Sounds correct analysysis to me. The SSMS generated rebuild scripts are very prone to this as well as they have `BEGIN TRAN ... COMMIT GO BEGIN TRAN ... COMMIT GO` so they can't just be run in SSMS without altering them or error handling or running one batch at a time. An error in one batch doesn't mean the next one won't run unless `sqlcmd` mode and `:on error exit`

Comment: @ErikE Nope I don't have the change script, but yes it did copy the old table to a temp table.  It created Tmp_MyTable, duplicated the structure and added my new column, inserted the data, dropped the original table, and renamed Tmp_MyTable back to MyTable. 

I double checked that the data was still there after running the script.. it was still there at that point.  Something about my UPDATE statement caused something to happen and it deleted every row.  This table has no triggers.

Comment: Yep, @ErikE has it exactly right. The Table Designer scripts have transaction control but lack appropiate exception-handling, a significant oversight. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `UPDATE` statement can't delete rows unless there is a trigger that performs the delete afterward, and you say the table has no triggers.

So it had to be the scenario I laid out for you in my comment: The rows did not get loaded properly to the new table, and the old table was dropped.

Note that it is even possible for it to have *looked* right for you, where the rows did get loaded at one point--if the transaction was not committed, and then (for example) later when your session was terminated the transaction was automatically rolled back. The transaction  could have been rolled back for other reasons, too.

Also, I may have gotten the order incorrect: it may create the new table under a new name, load the rows, drop the old table, and rename the new one. In this case, you may have been querying the wrong table to find out if the data had been loaded. I can't remember off the top of my head right now which way the table designer structures its scripts--there's more than one way to skin this cat.

Comment: Utterly reproducible as well. I tried `CREATE TABLE T (A INT DEFAULT 1,C INT DEFAULT 2)INSERT INTO T DEFAULT VALUES` then inserted `NOT NULL` column `B` between the columns in the designer and ran the generated script in SSMS. Empty table.

Comment: Thanks Erike for the explanation and Martin for testing it out yourself.  I guess feeding SSMS a not null column without a default value is a no-no.  Lesson learned

Comment: @user1003916 - In this case `SET XACT_ABORT ON;` and `:on error exit` would have stopped the issue. I haven't done an exhaustive review of the scripts generated by SSMS to see whether that would always be safe or not though.